# Help for identifying pinout of unknown mp3 chip

Tags: components, identification

I'm trying to use a cheap mp3 player to play song using Arduino, I couldn't find the datasheet of the main chip but I made some progress identifying some pins.

```
                 Pin
                1  16  Busy  
Play/Stop IO1   2  15  GND
Prev/Vol- IO2   3  14 
Next/Vol+ IO3   4  13
                5  12
                6  11 SPK -
                7  10 SPK Right
                8   9 SPK Left
```

This looks very similar to the picaxe by8001 and the WT5001

I will need some ideas to find the datasheet or at least find RX/TX/ADC KEY pins.

[image: unknown_chip_JL]

More pics [here](https://flic.kr/s/aHskCGVX5w)

Note: Why not use mp3 module for arduino? I try the WTV020 with no luck, I could buy a dfplayer or the WT5001, but this mp3 player cost 1/5 of 
those modules.

Comment: How is the arduino involved? Are you using it to play and pause the MP3 player? Also I believe the company of the IC is Chinese, which explains why a datasheet is hard to find (also why it is so cheap). I could be wrong.

Comment: Without a better picture of the board is hard to say. What makes you think it has a serial port?

Comment: @Passerby I'm trying to identify the logo. It looks like the Greek character Pi.

Comment: I didn't even notice that. I thought it was JL.

Comment: @Passerby I think it has serial because this is very similar to the by8001 and the wt5001. Play, Next. Prev pins work, like the data sheets of the original chips. Also when pulldown with a 20k resistir on pins 3 and 4 they change to fast foward and fast reweind.  And those data sheets mention similar key mapings using diferent resistor on the pull down. And there are 7 unkown pins left, they could be vcc, tx, rx, key1, key2. One of those similar chips has bat+ and bat-. And this board has a rechargable battery and no other chips on board that could charge the battery.

Comment: @Bradman175 arduino while play different audio for different sensor inputs on arduino like a talking toy.

Comment: @James ?? Have other kinds of sensors do play and pause?

Comment: @Bradman175 Sorry I don't understand your question.

Comment: @James Sorry I badly worded that question. What I meant was: Are you using other types of sensors that will be making the MP3 player Play/Pause/Stop the music?

Comment: @Bradman175 Well, the general idea is that the Arduino will be the only one controling de MP3, but it till process severeal inputs in order to decide the sound to be played. For example if a vibration sensor is activated play sound1, then stop. If to much noise in the ambient (Sound sensor) play sound2. If too dark (LDR) play sound3.

Comment: @James Ah so the arduino can switch between which songs can be played. Well unfortunately since we don't know the IC, it would be almost impossible to know its functionality.

Comment: @Passerby I just found something, the board is call Jtron (the symbol was not Pi), you can buy it here, but there is not explain of the chip specification :( https://www.amazon.com/Jtron-20050299-MP3-Decoder-Board/dp/B010WOAQG6

Comment: @Bradman175 Searching for Jtron I found this http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=230904.msg1918200#msg1918200 If Zapro schematic is correct there is no serial port after all

Comment: The Company is called JieLi based in Hong Kong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a common design for these cheap mp3 players.
And the labels seem to be pure confusion or some kind of serial number.

There’s a version with and without LCD display, the chips are probably very simlar. The LCD version displays "ic type: ht2836 firmware ver v1.00".

The chips seem to be sold by [chipkingdom](http://www.chipkingdom.com/en/pic.asp) (the site also has a few "datasheets", look out for the GPDxxxx MP3 stuff).
GP is for [General Plus](http://www.generalplus.com) who designed these chips to begin with, but no further information is available on their website.

Here are some further more or less interesting links that deal with the chip:

- http://psmay.com/2014/09/18/teardown-1-45-chinese-mp3-player/
- http://tarkus-notes.com/en/chinese-mp3-player-ipod-shuffle-clone/
- http://overskill.alexshu.com/cheaphack-a-2-5-chinese-mp3-player-for-its-128x64-mini-lcd/
- http://homeant.000space.com/articles/4/4/?i=1
- https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=361444.0
- http://ameblo.jp/akinas/entry-11978758574.html
- http://web.archive.org/web/20160302021815/http://www.ieyong.net/en/chanpinzhongxin-259928-0-item-459063.html

Answer (score 2):

It is a Jerry mp3 AC1082, a cheap encoder Chinese IC

Answer (score 2):

After what felt like ages of googling, I found that it's made by Jie Li Electronics, a company based in Taiwan that mainly makes transistors, resistors, and capacitors. They also make these ICs but I couldn't find any info on them. I'm looking for a similar IC from this same company, but I can't find any info on these.

So that logo isn't a Pi, it's actually a JL like most of us assumed it was.