# JL (or maybe something else) misterious branded IC's, what is the origin?

Tags: integrated-circuit, components, identification, microprocessor, manufacturing

**Edit 12/31/2019:** Thanks to Mariano Dupont:

Found it: Zhuhai Jieli Technology [zh-jieli.com](http://www.zh-jieli.com/)

---

Take a look at this example of an IC found on a circuit board:

---

[image: JL branded ic]

---

Brand is found on many PCB's of Chinese/India manufacturers of different kind of devices, mostly consumer based.

For example, there are many printed logo's on IC's listed on [this](https://www.elnec.com/en/support/ic-logos/?method=logo) site, however you cannot find this JL (or sort of italic pi?) logo, unable to find it anywhere. Also when this logo is on an IC and searching for the part-number/IC model number, always lead to a dead end, I am never able to find a datasheet.

So what is this misterious brand, is it actually a brand, what's the origin and actual name of the manufacturer? And is the part-number/IC model number really a description of what it is or just a random number?

Comment: If the part number was legible and/or quoted in the question someone might recognise it.

Comment: The question looks legit to me. A close vote doesn't mean the question is closed, it will be voted on, if you feel that this is wrong, bring it up with a moderator. I only see one person here that isn't nice, although some of the comments could have been deleted

Comment: OP has checked an answer as favorite. No need to change status.

Comment: @Sparky You meant "accepted", not "favorite" (this is another, unrelated, feature of SE). Anyway, the "closed" state and "has an accepted answer" are completely unrelated. Even if OP has accepted an answer, if the question is on-topic, it doesn't have to be closed. Anyone else should be able to add another (possibly even better) answer. So, yes, if enough people consider this is on-topic, the status has to change.

Comment: From a similar product on AliExpress it seems that the brand name is Jieli. Here the link: US $18.00 | Jieli Bluetooth Chip Jieli AC6901A JL Stereo Multi-IO Port Support LCD Screen and Digital Tube
https://a.aliexpress.com/5t2RaKLe

Comment: Found it: Zhuhai Jieli Technology http://www.zh-jieli.com/

Comment: @MarianoDupont Hai, cool man! Thanks!

Comment: May I ask what was the functionality of this chip, or moreover what device it is from?

Comment: @h0r53 I cannot remember exactly. I think it is from a MP3-player however they als put these 'formfactor' IC's inside bluetooth devices/headphones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember this logo. Don't ask me where I know it from. A bit digging showed that we had a similar request for this chip already:

[Help for identifying pinout of unknown mp3 chip](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/243531/help-for-identifying-pinout-of-unknown-mp3-chip)

Manufacturer is probably called "Jerry" or "Jay Management". Probably there simply is no english name for the manufacturer.

Maybe some Chinese speaking member can chime in and use some Chinese search engine fu to find out more.

Comment: Found out it is a mirrored pi sign. I isolated the logo and drop into google and google showed me a pi sign that looks very similar. Also scan it with OCR software online but nothing.

Comment: I bought a cheap JQ-D015BT MP3 decoder board with USB/TF/Bluetooth/AUX connectivity. It has a JL (or π) logo and the chip code is either AS18DHO171 (letter O) or AS18DH0171 (digit 0). The former search string yields some results in Google. - And why has this question been closed? The last paragraph reads like a perfectly clear question to me.

Comment: It is: Zhuhai Jieli Technology, see also my answer for link.