# HBQ-i7 Bluetooth Chip Identification

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, bluetooth

I was recently in Hong Kong and decided to purchase a knockoff Airpod to tear it down and see how it was engineered to help me in my own design process. I got to the mainboard and found the single chip which runs the operation marked "AC1815E8K193-9A0" (It may also be "AG...") and uses a logo which looks like the Pi symbol. A search turns up nothing and I'm struggling to find anything online about this model. Any ideas of where to search or any leads would be much appreciated! I'd also be glad to provide more pictures if desired [image]

Comment: It looks like it could be "JL" too

Comment: Probably some proprietary chip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one I found when searching JL chip logo: -

[image]

Note that this is an AC.... part so try and find who JL is....

But the chip number doesn't match the AC6905A number so maybe they use some form of coding.

Following the part number protocol used in the picture your device might be an AC1815E from JL (who appear to be based in China). Maybe it's related to JL audio who make weatherproof bluetooth modules: -

[image]

See also [this SE question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/367331/jl-or-maybe-something-else-misterious-branded-ics) and [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/243531/help-for-identifying-pinout-of-unknown-mp3-chip) where others have tried to find parts made by these guys but not very successfully. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

I bought a Bluetooth earphone just for the fun if it and i found the same, well different number but the JL chip.
It is apparently fron a company called Zhuhai Jieli Technology Co., Ltd. And here's the site http://www.zh-jieli.com.
But not much on the site. Then i found a listing for some similar ICs. https://www.yoycart.com/Product/540545907979/
I might try tinkering with it.[image]

Answer (score 2):

I also got the same with different chip number AC1820E8M903-9A0. After bit of searching I got the company name Zhuhai Jieli Technology Co., Ltd and website: http://www.zh-jieli.com/.
But on that site there no information available regarding this chips.[image]

Answer (score 2):

This logo is JL and stands for Jie Li (Electronics).

I found JL brand

AC1513CF9J0T  1-06BT

in a very low cost bluetooth mini speaker which did not work when I purchased at HK$20 or US$2.56 for destruction to see whats it has inside.

BT may stand for Blue Tooth.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This logo JL is short for JieLi, a china IC company, advantage on Bluetooth, there is no much IC documents on the JieLi website, u can access https://yunthinker.taobao.com , this company is the 1st level agent of JL IC.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a datasheet either:

Tellur TLL161041 (access to 4 screws used by popping off the cloth cover) contains AS20BP04216-28B4 (20 pin TSSOP?) and LTK8002D (SO-8) amp and a SOTxx-5 near the micro USB connector, maybe a regulator or charger for the battery (glued into the case).

I was hoping for an external EEPROM for a chance to modify default behaviour (very loud startup and low-bat shutdown announcements with audio).

The chip has USB mass storage host and TF (SD card) capabilities for audio playback, uses 4 buttons and a microphone.

Here's a traced schematic of another bluetooth module:
http://sxemy-podnial.net/tag/as20bp01915-25a4/ ([Google Translate](https://sxemy--podnial-net.translate.goog/tag/as20bp01915-25a4/?_x_tr_sch=http&_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=nui)).

Comment: https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/jl-bluetooth-ic-id/