# Can't find the datasheet of cheap Bluetooth audio receiver

Tags: audio, integrated-circuit, bluetooth

[image]

The chip says JL AP24186-26A4, but I can't find datasheet anywhere. Every time it takes me to dead end. If someone know about it then please help.

Update:
Found that it's Bluetooth 5.0 based audio receiver.
http://dientunguyenkiet.com/module-mp3-fm-bluetooth-5-0qd008-id144.html

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gCEA.jpg)

Comment: Datasheets may not be publicly available from manufacturers who only sell to wholesale commercial or industrial customers. In any case, don't buy things you can't find the datasheet for.

Comment: I have used this chip n working fine. Only thing is that we have to connect 3.7volt supply. I used lithium ion battery. On vcc we have to connect +ve 3.7volt thats it. Rest of the point I.e. gnd, l out, r out n gnd for the speaker.

Comment: @Arunchoudhary This would be better if you could explain the source of your information suggesting that the supply voltage should be 3.7 volts.  Presumably what you actually mean is that it is designed for single cell operation, in which case it probably would accept up to 4.2 volts and would also likely work below 3.7 volts though a low voltage cutout may trip at some point... [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: Another thread about ICs from this manufacturer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/388067/hbq-i7-bluetooth-chip-identification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already searched for the chip and didn't find with Google, chances are that you will never find this datasheet...

If I were in your situation, I would try to use this module just as every other
cheap Bluetooth module. If you succeed, good. But, if don't.. well, with no datasheet, you have nothing to be lost here; the only thing to do would be order another cheap bluetooth module.

If you send a photo of the back of the PCB, we could give more hints. This is my "educated guess":

[image]

```
AUDIO
1 Left (or right) output +
2 Common (audio ground)
3 Right (or left) output +

POWER
4 +Vcc
5 GND
```

If left and right are interchanged, well, who cares? But you can change they, if needed.

Look that pad 5 is connected to a great area of PCB, that's why I guess that pad 5 is GND.
There is a white retangle around pads 4 and 5, so that it seems that they're the power connection.

Probably pads 2 and 5 are connected one to another? (check the other side of the board)

For probe this board: connect pad 4 to 3.3V and pad 5 to GND, and search with a cell phone for a bluetooth device.  If don't suceed, try at 5V.

Comment: I've attached the back side image, can you suggest something. Like, DP and DM

Comment: It seems that DP and DM are USB signals: "**D**ata **P**lus" and "**D**ata **M**inus" = D+ and D-. Probably the USB is for connecting a flash drive.

Comment: I thought it was for programming this chip.

Comment: Yes, programming is a better guess... when I said that it could be for an USB drive, I wasn't aware that, if it were for an USB drive, there would be connections for play/pause/stop/next buttons, too! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I found the datasheet corresponding to the AC6926A4 chip, in the following link:

> Encontré el datasheet correspondiente al chip AC6926A4, en el siguiente link:

http://en.tome-sz.com/lanyayinxiang_view.aspx?nid=3&typeid=74&id=207

http://en.tome-sz.com/Admin/Others/DownloadsPage.aspx?nid=3&id=207&tag=0&ref=lanyayinxiang_view&t=d903642155cb49f9

Answer (score 0):

I have found this datasheet in case anyone will need it, i have the same chip as you presented in the post from a car mp3 modulator which i have repurposed it into a motorcycle intercom, but my job was a bit simpler, i had to find out which pins are DAC and VCC and found out this chip was a match, after some measures on the oscillometer and the rf antenna which i found to be on the same pins as the datasheet present, so i went ahead and tried the audio output pins and just worked in my case. I'm not sure about the other pins, so precede with caution.

S : http://www.chenbingdom.com/uploadfile/20198911114328981.jpg [image]

Comment: Isn't that for a completely different chip than asked in the question?

Comment: Andr8 - Hi, Thanks for trying to help. However (a) As commented above, that looks like a schematic for a different IC (AC6936D vs. AP24186 in the question). Please explain how that schematic applies. Or are you posting this just in case it is any help (or perhaps none)? (b) Since you have copied material from elsewhere, please [edit] the answer to add the [required reference](/help/referencing). If that image came from an online source (webpage, PDF, video etc.) then please add the source *name* and its *link* (URL). If the source is offline, please add a normal citation (see the rule). TY